# Angular template driven form validation : should I post ngModel or form.value?

Tags: angular, angular2-form-validation

This is a question about good practices with Angular 2+ template driven forms validation.

When I have

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    firstname : <input [(ngModel)]="user.firstname" name="firstname" />
    <button [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="post()">Post</button>
</form>
```

Should I do

```
post() {
    this.userService.post(this.user);
}
```

Or

```
post() {
    this.userService.post(this.form.value);
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your entity object (user in your example) has any properties, such as an ID, that are not included on the form ...

This code:

```
post() {
    this.userService.post(this.form.value);
}
```

Won't include them. So it would not include the Id of the user for example.

This code:

```
post() {
    this.userService.post(this.user);
}
```

Will include all of the user properties.

You can see this by defining your entity object like this:

```
export interface IUser {
    id: number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

Add the first and last name to your form as you did above, then add the following to your post:

```
    console.log('form: ' + JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
    console.log('entity: ' + JSON.stringify(this.user));
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to go with reactive form.

On the downside

> template driven form

is the form validation logic cannot be unit tested. The only way to test this logic is to run an end to end test with a browser, for example using a headless browser like `PhantomJs.`

Comment: Thanks, I might do that, yeah. But my question was not about unit testing.

Comment: i am just giving an example of downside of template driven form. thank you